# Recursive function with IO

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm having problems with the next code, the idea is to make a function which returns a list of words from a file with the directory in a tuple.

```
gainData:: [FilePath] -> IO [([String],String)]
gainData[] = []
gainData(xz:xc) = do
    temp <- readFileP xz
    return ((temp,xz) : gainData xc)
```

The function readFileP gets a list with all the words of a file.

```
readFileP:: FilePath -> IO [String]
```

For example i would want to get

```
[(["word","word1"],"fileAddress"),(["word","word1"],"fileAddress2")]
```

I don't know what's the problem, can somebody tell me please? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot do:

```
return ((temp,xz) : gainData xc)
```

The `gainData` function returns an `IO [something]` not just `[something]`.
You have to first extract the value returned:

```
res <- gainData xc
return $ (temp,xz) : res
```

The `varname <- action` does the following:

- It calls `action`, which in this case its `gainData xc`. This action returns an `IO something`
- It "extracts" the `something` from the `IO` and assign it to `varname`

in fact it works with any `Monad`, not just `IO`.

Also, in the first definition you are returning `[]`, but this is of type `[something]` while `gainData` should be of type `IO [something]` so you have to add a `IO` layer to it:

```
gainData [] = return []
```

`return` is "the opposite" of the `<-`. It takes a `something` and turns it into an `IO something`, which can be extracted using the `<-`.

Comment: I tried adding those 2 lines at the end of the program, now it displays the error Couldn't match expected type `IO [([String], String)]' with actual type `[a0]' In the expression: []
What's wrong with gainData [] = [] ?

Comment: @SeyrenGuile That's the opposite error. `gainData` must return a `IO [something]` not just `[something]` so use `return []` instead of `[]`.